# Explicitly closing FileInputStream

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I'm using a BitmapFactory to obtain a bitmap from a file.  The first argument in decodeStream is a stream.  I'm providing it with a new FileInputStream.  Do I need to explicitly close the stream instead?  Could this result in a memory leak?

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(x))
```

Maybe it should be?:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(x);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
fis.close();
```

I know bitmaps have a tendency to be leaky, this question is more about the FileInputStream than the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to close the stream.  Because the decode function doesn't know that there isn't more data to write, so it won't do it for you.  Not doing so isn't likely to cause a big memory leak, but can cause data not to be flushed to disk if the stream is buffered and will leave OS resources (file handles at a minimum) unreleased.